# Using C++ and WSL in VS Code for remote ARM64 device

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to build `main.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int count=0;
   vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

   for (const string& word : msg)
   {
      count++;
      cout << word << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

[Using C++ and WSL in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl) but it ends. This example I can build it on WSL directly

```
x86: g++-7 main.cpp -o main.x86_64
ARM64: aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ main.cpp -o main.arm64
```

My task.json file is

```
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "aarch64-linux-gnu-g++",
        "command": "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.arm64"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
```

How this can be built (cross-compiled) for remote ARM-target machines in VSCode and remotely debugged?

I have *IP* address for target ssh-machine, and locally on Win10/WSL I have installed "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"... I can do it manually it means cross-compile it and scp-ing to target and execute there.

Comment: i don't know why this happened, but passing `tasks.json` to gcc command is wrong. Did you use "compile file" while the `tasks.json` file was active?

Comment: Yes, that it was my mistake and try to run a build-task on wrongly activated file :(

Answer (score 0):

Partially, I succeeded - I installed native debug extension [Native Debug of WebFreak](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webfreak.debug)

```
    {
        "type": "gdb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program (SSH)",
        "target": "/home/root/peterb/bin/main.arm64",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "preLaunchTask": "aarch64-linux-gnu-g++",
        "ssh": {
           "host": "10.171.89.215",
           "cwd": "/home/root/peterb/bin",
           "user": "root",
           "password": "",
           "port": 22,
           "useAgent": false,
           "forwardX11": false
        }
    }
```

I manually copied the executable file `main.arm64` and `main.cpp` onto the arm64 machine. The executable code is launched and can be debugged.

[image]

The `"preLaunchTask": "aarch64-linux-gnu-g++",` do "*automatic build*".

Now I wanna do automatic copy from the project workspace from the host machine to the target machine?

Comment: Can't you use another VS task? Or use a pre task to aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ task?